# Unable to Retrieve SIM Phone Number and IMSI Number in Real Devices with Android API 29 and Above Using Kotlin Code

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I tried to retrieve the SIM phone number and IMSI number using Kotlin. However, it's not working on real devices with Android API 29 or above. The code works fine on emulators and Android 7.

I have included the required permissions in the manifest file. Here is my Kotlin code. Can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

```
    private var carrierName: String? = null
    private var displayName: String? = null
    private var slotIndex = 0
    private var number: String? = null
    private var countryIso: String? = null
    private var imsi: String? = null
    private var simId: String? = null




    init {
        carrierName = ""
        displayName = ""
        slotIndex = 0
        number = ""
        countryIso = ""
        imsi = ""
        simId = ""
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && subscriptionInfo!=null) {
            carrierName = subscriptionInfo.carrierName.toString()
            displayName = subscriptionInfo.displayName.toString()
            slotIndex = subscriptionInfo.simSlotIndex
            number = subscriptionInfo.number
            imsi = subscriptionInfo.subscriptionId.toString()
            simId = subscriptionInfo.iccId
            if (subscriptionInfo.countryIso != null && subscriptionInfo.countryIso.isNotEmpty()) {
                countryIso = subscriptionInfo.countryIso
            } else if (telephonyManager.simCountryIso != null) {
                countryIso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
            }
        }else {
            if (telephonyManager.simOperator != null) {
                carrierName = telephonyManager.simOperatorName
            }
            if (telephonyManager.simOperator != null) {
                displayName = telephonyManager.simOperatorName
            }
            if (telephonyManager.simCountryIso != null) {
                countryIso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
            }
            if (telephonyManager.subscriberId != null) {
                imsi = telephonyManager.subscriberId
            }

            if (telephonyManager.simSerialNumber != null) {
                simId = telephonyManager.simSerialNumber
            }

            if (telephonyManager.line1Number != null && telephonyManager.line1Number.isNotEmpty()) {
                number = telephonyManager.line1Number
            }
        }
    }
```

Manifest

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PRIVILEGED_PHONE_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the imsi from `telephonyManager.subscriberId`

```
    private var carrierName: String? = null
    private var displayName: String? = null
    private var slotIndex = 0
    private var number: String? = null
    private var countryIso: String? = null
    private var imsi: String? = null
    private var simId: String? = null

    init {
        carrierName = ""
        displayName = ""
        slotIndex = 0
        number = ""
        countryIso = ""
        imsi = ""
        simId = ""

        imsi = telephonyManager.subscriberId
        number = telephonyManager.line1Number

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1 && subscriptionInfo!=null) {
            carrierName = subscriptionInfo.carrierName.toString()
            displayName = subscriptionInfo.displayName.toString()
            slotIndex = subscriptionInfo.simSlotIndex
            
            simId = subscriptionInfo.iccId
            if (subscriptionInfo.countryIso != null && subscriptionInfo.countryIso.isNotEmpty()) {
                countryIso = subscriptionInfo.countryIso
            } else if (telephonyManager.simCountryIso != null) {
                countryIso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
            }
        }else {
            if (telephonyManager.simOperator != null) {
                carrierName = telephonyManager.simOperatorName
            }
            if (telephonyManager.simOperator != null) {
                displayName = telephonyManager.simOperatorName
            }
            if (telephonyManager.simCountryIso != null) {
                countryIso = telephonyManager.simCountryIso
            }

            if (telephonyManager.simSerialNumber != null) {
                simId = telephonyManager.simSerialNumber
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you a privlidged system app signed with the system's key?  Because you can't get READ_PRIVLIEGED_PHONE_STATE as a normal app, or as anything from the play store.

Comment: yes it's signed with the key